# How to install new Android emulators

Tags: android, android-studio

I've installed the latest Android Studio (2.2.3) on macOS and I've installed a few of the newest SDKs from the SDK manager.

I want to run a Nougat 7.0 emulator, but when I open AVD to create one, I only get Android 4.4.2 as an option.

What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: have you restarted studio after installing new images?

Comment: @OlegBogdanov indeed